# Open files on file server in apex 5

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I'm working on an apex 18.1 application where i have a file server (contains .pdf and .docx files) , and I'm trying to show those files on a report and make them possible to download.
Is there any way to establish this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do that.

You have to know URL to those files, which means that - when you enter it into your browser's address and press ENTER, you'll be prompted to open or save the file.

I have stored URLs into a table which looks like this:

```
SQL> select id_dokument, url
  2  from dokumentacija
  3  where id_dokument in (210, 204);

ID_DOKUMENT URL
----------- ---------------------------------------------
        204 http://my-ias/Od_07_mjerenje.doc
        210 http://my-ias/Od_08_meo.pdf

SQL>
```

In Apex (interactive) report, write a query which creates the "Download" link as

```
select 
  id_dokument, 
 '<a href="' || url || '" target="_blank">Download</a>' c_download
from dokumentacija
```

Navigate to `C_DOWNLOAD`'s properties and set "**Escape special characters**" to "**No**".

That's all; run the page, click the "Download" link and choose whether to open the file or save it.

Comment: By file server i mean the files are on a directory in the server. Im not sure how i am going to create url.